# Removing control characters from a text file

Tags: linux, text

I started a unix keystroke log with `script temp.txt`; however, it captures my keystrokes verbatim (backspaces, arrows, etc...).  What is the best way to remove the control characters from a file named `temp.txt` that I created with `script temp.txt`?

---

NOTE: I am [answering my own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does the job...

```
cat temp.txt | col -bx > no_control_chars.txt
```